# Are "Is there a better way than X" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

If a user asks a question akin to

```
I am currently using method A and getting X result which is slow. 
I am considering method B and hope it will be faster. Is there
another method that would work better in this situation?
```

does that fall under "primarily opinion based"? I'm not sure since it's asking an open ended question but its asking about a quantitative measurement, not "the best".

Comment: If it's a good question, I point the asker to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stijn Isn't code review focused on the existing code and not comparisons of different algorithms (which is kind of what the question is asking)?

Comment: I think these are extremely context dependent. Depending on the information provided and the language/technology being used there may be a clear, correct answer, or there may not. If the question involves technologies I don't know, I leave the question alone; if it's something I'm familiar with enough that I feel comfortable making the call I'll either vote to close or answer it.

Comment: i would feel that those are too broad.

Comment: @Daniel http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic lists *Performance* as on-topic, and the 6 questions under *I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?* suggest (imho) that such questions are on-topic. Might be valuable to get a regular from CR to share their input here.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, but it is dangerous. Better to package it so: "How to do X quickly? I do X in the way Y, but it is slow because Z. How to avoid that disadvantage?"

Comment: This is, IMO, a Code Review question and is therefore not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @double-beep: Don't know what's on or off topic on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but on Stack Overflow code improvement is entirely on topic. Here's one a asked a while back, it got 5 upvotes and 6 answers: [Improve speed of complex postgres query in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508979/improve-speed-of-complex-postgres-query-in-rails-app)